# My home does not have .pypirc file which is giving me an error while registering the python package to PyPI

Tags: python, ubuntu, pypi, python-packaging, pypiserver

I am using ubuntu and I have created a python package and it is ready to register on PyPI but when I use `python setup.py register` it is showing an error like this:

```
Server response (410): This API is no longer supported, instead simply upload the file.
```

I know that this is the error of not finding the .pypirc file but I don't know how to fix this because my home does not have the .pypirc file.Can't we just create the pypirc file?(just asking). Also there is a  different error when I use the register command in the virtualenv, I get this:

```
Server response (410): Gone (This API has been deprecated and removed from legacy PyPI in favor of using the APIs available in the new PyPI.org implementation of PyPI (located at https://pypi.org/). For more information about migrating your use of this API to PyPI.org, please see https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/#uploading. For more information about the sunsetting of this API, please see https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-June/030766.html)
```

and here is my setup.py file

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='Utilitarian',
      version='0.1',
      description='little description',
      url='https://github.com/Shivams334/Utilitarian.git',
      author='Shivam Sharma',
      author_email='shivams334@gmail.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['Utilitarian'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You need to create `.pypirc` file by yourself in your `HOME` directory

```
touch ~/.pypirc
```

this file should contain the following code, put you login and password from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi)

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi
    pypitest

[pypitest]
repository = https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
username = <your username>
password = <your password>

[pypi]
repository = https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
username = <your username>
password = <your password>
```

Because you put you login and password into this file, you may want to change it's permission so that only you can read and write it.

```
chmod 600 ~/.pypirc
```

And after it you can try to register your package, by the way I hightly recommend you using [twine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twine) library to load your package, just install it

```
pip install twine
```

Then  make a distribution for your package

```
python setup.py install
```

This command will create a `dist` folder with your module packed inside then register your project (if necessary):

```
twine register dist/example-project-x.y.z.tar.gz
```

after it you can upload your package to pip with the following command

```
twine upload dist/*
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @zaytsev and yes, I tried to make the .pypirc file by both manually and on terminal but it is still not working because my home is not giving the permission to make any new file.

Comment: Looks like this changed recently, you need to delete the line with thre repository, https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/#uploading, then you dont need to register just upload